# Error during saving FeedItem with type ContentPost using API above 35

Tags: api, attachment, feeditem

I am trying to save **FeedItem** with attachments. In that case I set type of FeedItem to ContentPost. During saving FeedItem I am getting 2 errors of **FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION** type:

```
ContentFileName is a required field for feed posts of type ContentPost: Content File Name
ContentData is a required field for feed posts of type ContentPost: Content Data
```

And here magic starts, because I am using **API version 52** and I know from documentation that fields ContentFileName, ContentData are obsolet for my version and I even can't see them in my WSDL file.

Have anyone occured similar problem and know any solution? Maybe I have to configure something on Salesforce side?

I would be grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, we are not supposed to insert FeedItems as "ContentPost" anymore. Instead:

- Insert them without specifying a Type. You probably get a "TextPost".
- Insert the FeedAttachment, specifying the FeedEntityId - and hey presto - your FeedItem morphed into a "ContentPost".

Comment: That was very simple solution. Thank you for fast response! :)